# I am getting error in VB6.0

Tags: visual-basic

I'm getting a runtime error as `20728-f`.

I got the solution to register `cpre23.dll` and `dwmapi.dll`. However I can't find the `cpre23.dll` file.

Where can I find this DLL file, or how else can I rectify this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The DLLs you referenced are from the Crystal Report Engine Library.  This library isn't freely distributable so you shouldn't find it available for download.  If you're not a licensed user you should become one.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this link out](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/196193-Runtime-error--f.aspx)

if this dll is crystal report - do you have it installed ?

Comment: I tried that one also but it was not helpful. I need a URL to download cpre23.dll file